# Force git over SSL (Ubuntu config)

Tags: git, ssl, config

Is there a way, when a git:// protocol is asked for (on an Ubuntu system) to force git to use https:// instead?  I'm on a work network that won't allow the port/protocol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tell git to rewrite URLs on the fly,

> `url.<base>.insteadOf`
>
> Any URL that starts with this value will be rewritten to start,
>   instead, with . In cases where some site serves a large number
>   of repositories, and serves them with multiple access methods, and
>   some users need to use different access methods, this feature allows
>   people to specify any of the equivalent URLs and have Git
>   automatically rewrite the URL to the best alternative for the
>   particular user, even for a never-before-seen repository on the site.
>   When more than one insteadOf strings match a given URL, the longest
>   match is used.
>   http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config

Try this:

```
git config url.https://.insteadOf git://
```

Comment: Well one day you will come across a site which does support git but not https then you will ask a question here to find out what is going on ;)

Answer (score 1):

Not every server supports both protocols at the same time so there is no way of knowing if the server actually supports https.

Comment: What about being able to set it for a given command?  Like, when running yeoman, for example?